# Java enum values

Tags: java, tcp, enums

How is the value of an enum calculated? Does the compiler give it a static value? What kind of value is it?

The reason I ask is because I was wondering what the consequences of using enum values over a tcp (or any inter-process) connection would be. (By enum value I mean `Enum.VALUE`) Obviously you wouldn't be able to construct packets compatible with your program from another language unless you knew the pre-determined values of each enum. So is it possible to figure out the "real" values of each? And will two Java programs using the same enum "class" file understand each other?

This is purely theoretical, please no scoldings. Pointers are good, though.

Answer (score 4):

As has been explained, don't rely on underlying implementations.  Instead, design your enum to store this sort of information under your control.  Imagine you have three commands to send to some embedded controller, done by writing a bit pattern to a register.  You want to use enums to give you a high-level representation of the commands, but at some point you need those pesky bit patterns:

```
public enum EmbeddedControllerCommand {

    FOO(0x001), BAR(0x010), BAZ(0x100);

    private int bitPattern = 0;

    EmbeddedControllerCommand(int bitPattern) {
        this.bitPattern = bitPattern;
    }

    public int getBitPattern() {
        return this.bitPattern;
    }

}
```

Just call `EmbeddedControllerCommand.FOO.getBitPattern()` to get the command pattern for the FOO command.

Answer (score 2):

If you refer to the [Enum JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) you can read that the [Enum.ordinal()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal%28%29) method returns a numeric constant value which is determined by the order of the Enum declarations in the class file.

For example, consider these enum constants in alphabetical order:

```
public enum Fruit{
    APPLE, // APPLE.ordinal()  == 0
    ORANGE;// ORANGE.ordinal() == 1
    PEAR,  // PEAR.ordinal()   == 2
}
```

But if we add BANANA in its alphabetical position, see how the values would change, breaking any code that relies on them:

```
public enum Fruit{
    APPLE, // APPLE.ordinal()  == 0
    BANANA,// BANANA.ordinal() == 1
    ORANGE;// ORANGE.ordinal() == 2
    PEAR,  // PEAR.ordinal()   == 3
}
```

This means that, so long as you're using the same version of the source code, you can rely on the underlying value being the same, and can use it for situations where there are no other options. I say no other options because by making your code dependent on the order of the enums, it makes the code more fragile, whereas if you aren't relying on the ordinal value you can reorder existing or insert new enum constants at will.

Now, would you accept a mild scolding for not reading the JavaDocs thoroughly before post? :)

Answer (score 2):

in Java Enums do have integer reference that Java calls ordinal. For example you can do `yourEnumVariable.ordinal()` to get the int number of the enum variable. The numbers are assigned in a way that first in the list gets number 0, second number 1 and so on.

However in your case it sounds like you should not be concerned about what is the internal representation of enums. You should decide on what kind of protocol you will use to transfer information. After that you can think of how to transfer enum values. You'll probably have to anyway build some mapping classes for the protocol to map from Java to the protocol.

Comment: +1 for indicating about the protocol and mapping. this is even better than my answer

Answer (score 0):

You should not rely the pre-assinged value of enum given by Java compiler. Different language has different scheme to deal with enum. In Java, enum can be treated like a class and objects (not exactly for the same purpose) so you can create a constructor in your enum and initialize the enum to the value you want. Here is a fairly clear examples:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html